# JFrame labels appear overlapped

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

i just programmed a program which has a `JFrame` containing an array of `JLabel` components. The array gets the position of the single labels assigned by a for-loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<label_entries.length; i++){
    label_entries[i].setLocation(10, i*30);
    label_entries[i].setSize(120,30);
    dialog.add(label_entries[i]);   
}
```

Do not get confused, my frame's name is "dialog".

There is one simple problem: The for-loop doesn't work like a for-loop should, and I don't know why, here is the result in my frame:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oEnE.png).

Don't care about the single label entries, the interesting thing is the position of `Telefon`.

If I set the beginning of the loop to the following, it is the same problem, just with another label.

```
for(int i=0; i<label_entries.length-1; i++){...}
```

### Here is the full code

```
JFrame dialog = new JFrame();
dialog.setBounds(25, 50, 500, 500);
dialog.setTitle("Eintrag hinzufügen");
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setVisible(true);

JLabel[] label_entries = new JLabel[11];
JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[11];
label_entries[0] = new JLabel("Vorname :");
label_entries[1] = new JLabel("Nachname :");
label_entries[2] = new JLabel("Nummer :");
label_entries[3] = new JLabel("Geburtstag :");
label_entries[4] = new JLabel("Land :");
label_entries[5] = new JLabel("PLZ :");
label_entries[6] = new JLabel("Stadt :");
label_entries[7] = new JLabel("Strasse :");
label_entries[8] = new JLabel("Hausnummer :");
label_entries[9] = new JLabel("E-Mail :");
label_entries[10] = new JLabel("Telefon :");

for(int i=0; i<label_entries.length; i++){
    label_entries[i].setLocation(10, i*30);
    label_entries[i].setSize(120,30);
    dialog.add(label_entries[i]);   
}
```

This should be easier to understand.

Comment: *"Do not get confused, my frame's name is "dialog"."* An easy way to 'not get confused' is for the person asking the question to not use confusing names for classes, attributes or methods. While you are creating a new code to demonstrate the problem, rename anything so confusing you feel compelled to comment on it. And speaking of 'new code'. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem is that you are setting absolute positions of your components. Typically a `LayoutManager` is used for this purpose.

To clear whatever the default layout manager of a `JFrame`'s content pane is, set it to `null` just after creating the frame.

```
JFrame dialog = new JFrame();
dialog.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers,
i just used this method at another JFrame and i cant explain why i did not use it this time...

Answer (score 1):

As the javadoc of [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) says:

> The default content pane will have a `BorderLayout` manager set on it.

Javadoc of [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) says:

> A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and center. Each region may contain no more than one component, and is identified by a corresponding constant: `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST`, and `CENTER`. When adding a component to a container with a border layout, use one of these five constants, for example:
>
> ```
> Panel p = new Panel();
> p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
> p.add(new Button("Okay"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
> ```
>
> As a convenience, `BorderLayout` interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant `CENTER`:
>
> ```
> Panel p2 = new Panel();
> p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
> p2.add(new TextArea());  // Same as p.add(new TextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
> ```

Since you call the 1-arg version of `add()`, all your JLabels are added with `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and so the last one wins, and the `BorderLayout` manager then auto-positions it at left-center.

To prevent that from happening, just remove the layout manager:

```
dialog.setLayout(null);
```